# Issue with Static array of pointers pointing to Child class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So I have an appliance class which is an abstract class and then 3 other children classes that inherit from it

In my main, I create an array of pointers of type appliance

```
Appliance *InStock[100];
```

Then I create one of my child class objects in the main

```
InStock[k]= new Oven();
```

But when I call one of my function it calls the appliance virtual function and not my overiden function in the Oven class

```
InStock[k]->WriteData()
```

Which calls the Appliance version and not the oven verstion

```
virtual void WriteData() const { cout<< modelNumber<< " "<< serialNumber;}
```

OverRidden in Oven class

```
void Refrigerator::WriteData() {
Appliance::WriteData();
string tempBool= "F";
if (frostFree){
    tempBool="T";
}
cout<< capacity<< " "<< tempBool<< endl;

}
```

This has to be something with the pointers because the pointer thinks its an appliance when it should be an Oven.

Thanks any help at all.

Comment: _"OverRidden in Oven class `Refrigerator::`"_ Wut??

Comment: Use the `override` keyword with overridden functions to catch such errors.

Comment: @user0042 `override` is not a keyword. But yeah

Comment: @M.M Could you enlighten me what's the exact difference of a [specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) and a _keyword_. Are specifiers something like extensible decorators (attributes)?

Comment: @M.M [Found it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have 2 different `WriteData` functions, one is `const` and another is not.

`const` part is actually a part of the function signature, which means the child class defines a new function rather than overriding the base class function. It is because their signatures don't match.  Due to this compiler does not treat them as a overwritten.

You have make both `const` or "not" `const` to call child class function.

Comment: It's notable that the `override` keyword exists to catch that kind of signature mismatches.